Regression learning procedure recommendations for learning discrete functions
I am working on learning a discrete function  $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$ where $U \subseteq \{0, 1\}^n$. In my application, $n$ is relatively low-dimensional (ranging between 30 and 70). For any given $ x \in U $, calculating $ f(x)$ requires solving a computationally expensive optimization problem. Due to the time-sensitive nature of my application, I prefer to learn the function $f$ rather than repeatedly solving the optimization problem. I am seeking algorithmic recommendations for approaching this regression problem.
Further, I suspect there is a lot of structure inherent within $f$, but this structure has a more discrete flavor. Examples of discrete structures are sub-modularity, sub-additivity etc. I am also interested in methods that can incorporate such discrete structural priors when learning the regression function.

Deep neural nets can model complex relationships. Might also be worth trying random forest regression, since it's an efficient model for capturing non-linear behaviour. I'd try various models (e.g. neural nets, random forests, gradient boosted algorithms), and see which fares best at generalising to unseen data. I think it'd be useful to know how large the dataset is.
